# listing conditionally an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to list all files and folders in a given directory in C, the following code errors out and i cant figure out whats wrong

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

enum {
    WALK_OK = 0,
    WALK_BADPATTERN,
    WALK_BADOPEN,
};

int walk_directories(const char *dir, const char *pattern, char* strings[])
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    regex_t reg;
    DIR *d; 
    int i = 0;
    //char array[256][256];

    if (regcomp(&reg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB))
    return WALK_BADPATTERN;
    if (!(d = opendir(dir)))
    return WALK_BADOPEN;
    while (entry = readdir(d))
    if (!regexec(&reg, entry->d_name, 0, NULL, 0) )
            //puts(entry->d_name);
        strings[i] = (entry->d_name);
        i++;
    closedir(d);
    regfree(&reg);

    return WALK_OK;
}

void main()
{
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    char *homedir = pw->pw_dir;
    strcat(homedir, "/.themes");

    int n = 0;
    char *array[256][100];
    char *array2[256][100];

    walk_directories(homedir, "", array);
        for (n = 0; n < 256; n++)
        {
            //do stuff here later, but just print it for now
            printf ("%s\n", array[n]);
        }

    walk_directories("/usr/share/themes", "", array2);
        for (n = 0; n < 256; n++)
        {
            //do stuff here later, but just print it for now
            printf ("%s\n", array2[n]);
        }
}
```

The error at compile time is

```
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:42:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’ [enabled by default]
test2.c:48:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘walk_directories’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test2.c:15:5: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[100]’
test2.c:52:6: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
test2.c:55:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘walk_directories’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test2.c:15:5: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[100]’
test2.c:59:6: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
```

If it helps, I've implemented what I want already in python, this is the desired result for C

```
import os
DATA_DIR = "/usr/share"

def walk_directories(dirs, filter_func):
    valid = []
    try:
    for thdir in dirs:
        if os.path.isdir(thdir):
            for t in os.listdir(thdir):
                if filter_func(os.path.join(thdir, t)):
                     valid.append(t)
    except:
    logging.critical("Error parsing directories", exc_info=True)
    return valid

def _get_valid_themes():
    """ Only shows themes that have variations for gtk+-3 and gtk+-2 """
    dirs = ( os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "themes"),
         os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".themes"))
    valid = walk_directories(dirs, lambda d:
            os.path.exists(os.path.join(d, "gtk-2.0")) and \
            os.path.exists(os.path.join(d, "gtk-3.0")))
    return valid

print(_get_valid_themes())
```

thank you

[EDIT]
thanks for the help, only problem im having now is the printf's all spit out rubbish instead of what i expected, ive tried a few things and the while loop looks like this now

```
    while (entry = readdir(d))
    if (!regexec(&reg, entry->d_name, 0, NULL, 0) )
            //printf("%s\n",entry->d_name);
        strcpy(strings[i], (entry->d_name));
        //strings[i] = (entry->d_name);
        printf("%i\n",i);
        i++;
    closedir(d);
```

the i doesnt get printed properly either, this is all i get from the 3 printf statements

```
0
Adwaita2





















\@




0
Radiance

��





\@



�K��
� `���
����
�


��
�
.N=

�O��
�

�
```

should mention that if i enable

```
       printf("%s\n",entry->d_name);
```

then it prints the expected output though

Comment: Actually, you don't have any errors. The type of diagnostic you are getting is called "warning", and you can resolve it by including `<string.h>`. Google.

Comment: @H2CO3, he does have some errors, it's just that the compiler is called them warnings.  For example, the mismatched pointer warnings it's showing will cause bizarre operation.  I'd call that an error in the program, even though the compiler deems them 'warning' and not 'error'.

Comment: @CarlNorum In this case, he should have posted the errors as well. (You're right anyway, one should pay attention to warnings as well, but still... Wording...)

Comment: Also, `void main()`? Barf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should include `string.h` to get the declaration of `strcat(3)`.
2. In your declaration:

   ```
   int walk_directories(const char *dir, const char *pattern, char* strings[])
   ```

   The `char  *strings[]` is just syntactic sugar meaning `char **strings`.  Since you're passing a 2D array, that won't work.  It looks to me like you're intending to make two arrays of strings, but that's not what these declarations do:

   ```
   char *array[256][100];
   char *array2[256][100];
   ```

   You probably don't want the `*`s there.  If you take them off, you can change the signature of `walk_directories` to this:

   ```
   int walk_directories(const char *dir, const char *pattern, char strings[][100])
   ```

   And it should work, with the necessary changes inside your function to match.  As a bonus, this change will make your `printf` calls start working, too.
3. It looks like you're missing some braces around your `while` loop body.

Comment: got a minor problem with the printf calls now though, ive added it to the main question, they only seem to put out rubbish characters, its some problem with the code in the while loop it seems.

Comment: If you print the strings in the loop where you do the `strcpy`, are they right?  Do you fill the arrays with all 256 strings?

Comment: yes, there right, i dont fill all 256 no, i just picked that as its more than the number of arrays ill ever get, it seems the braces were the problem, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The first warning indicates that the compiler cannot figure out what arguments the `strcat()` function is supposed to take. Since this is a standard C function, this warning means that you are missing a `#include` directive. Specifically, you need to `#include <string.h>`. When you fix this, you may find that you get different errors and warnings, so work from there.